# PHP - Get directory contents and info and output array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm working on the following but have become stumped as to how to get this to output.

I have the following which scans the directory contents, then gets the info and saves it as an array:

```
   //SCAN THE DIRECTORY
    $directories = scandir($dir);
    $directinfo = array();
    foreach($directories as $directory){
        if ($directory === '.' or $directory === '..') continue;
        if(!stat($dir.'/'.$directory)){

        } else {
            $filestat = stat($dir.'/'.$directory);
            $directinfo[] = array(
                'name' => $directory,
                'modtime' => $filestat['mtime'],
                'size' => $filestat['size']
            );

        }
    }
```

When trying to output it however, I'm just getting single letters with a lot of breaks. Im obviously missing something here with the output loop.

```
    foreach($directinfo as $dirInfo){
        foreach($dirInfo as $drInfo){
            for ($x=0; $x<=2; $x++) {
                <span>"".$drInfo[$x]."<br/></span>";

            }
        }
    }
```

Help is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: try to omit for loop (for ($x=0; $x<=2; $x++) {})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already did everything just remove your `for loop`.

and try to do the following-

```
       foreach($directinfo as $dirInfo){
            foreach($dirInfo as $key=>$drInfo){             
                echo "<span>".$key."=>".$drInfo."<br/></span>";             
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your dealing with a 2d array, but treating it like a 3d array.

what does

```
foreach($directinfo as $dirInfo){
    foreach($dirInfo as $drInfo){
        var_dump($drInfo);
    }
}
```

give you?

Answer (score 0):

You're building a single array, dirInfo.

Php foreach takes the array first;

```
foreach($dirInfo as $info) { 
 echo "<span>" . $info['name'] . "</span>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function. It will return you list of all files with path.

```
// to list the directory structure with all sub folders and files
function getFilesList($dir)
{
    $result = array();
    $root = scandir($dir);
    foreach($root as $value) {
        if($value === '.' || $value === '..') {
            continue;
        }
        if(is_file("$dir$value")) {
            $result[] = "$dir$value";
            continue;
        }
        if(is_dir("$dir$value")) {
            $result[] = "$dir$value/";
        }
        foreach(getFilesList("$dir$value/") as $value)
        {
            $result[] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```